# Third party libraries of Deno having package.json?

Tags: javascript, deno

Correct me if I'm wrong but Deno should not understand the concept of `package.json` nor `node_modules`, if that's the case, why there are couple of third party libraries such as [lodash](https://deno.land/x/lodash@4.17.19), [dayjs](https://deno.land/x/dayjs@v1.10.7) still having `package.json` in their repo?

Comment: I think your question is a little bit incomplete. What does `lodash` or `dayjs` have to do with `deno`?

Comment: I think its because deno has invented just before last couple of moths back. These libraries are built before that. I think that's the reason why.

Comment: @AgilAtakishiyev: If you click on both the link above, you will be routed to deno.land xxx which i assume it's the deno variant of both aforementioned packages?

Comment: Oh now i get it, this is because that packages on their on have some third party dependencies, deno just ships those packages built version, and to build those packages they should have their own dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can provide some historical context here; The first version of the `deno.land/x` registry worked by having a list of repositories that was kept directly in the GitHub repository, anyone could submit a PR to add any other public repository to that list and copied over to `deno.land/x`. As the site scaled and more and more people wanted to create modules, the model was switched to use GitHub webhooks that have to be set up by the repository owner instead.

`lodash` and `dayjs` we submitted in the early days of `deno.land/x` by community members, so the files of the repo were copied 1:1 over to `deno.land/x` and that's why you see the `package.json` file in there -- it's literally the same repository content as `lodash`.

While the file is available through `deno.land/x` via the browser or curl, Deno will never actually reach for it; It'll just look at your entrypoint and walk the dependency graph from there, only looking at JS/TS files. In fact I wouldn't be surprised if the versions of `lodash` and `dayjs` available on `deno.land/x` were completely broken in Deno (at least without import maps.)

Comment: Any examples on how to use import maps to use those `deno.land/x` libraries?